# Java jcombobox different text in its dropdown and different text in its textfield

Tags: java, jcombobox

I want to create a jcombobox that will have the following appearance behaivour:
  1) in the dropdown list each line should be a code number and an item name.
 2) when the user selects one of those lines, in the textfield component of the combobox only the code number should appear and not the item name.
[(Something like this)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36UuM.png)

How can i do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not so hard to do that using two steps:

1. Your `JComboBox` items must be an Object for example:

   ```
   public class Item {
        private String number;
        private String name;
        // Constructor + Setters and Getters
    }
   ```
2. A `ListCellRenderer` which customize how to render the values in the popup list or in the text-field of `JComboBox`:

   ```
       JComboBox<Item> jc = new JComboBox<Item>();
       jc.setRenderer(new ListCellRenderer<Item>() {
           @Override
           public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
                   JList<? extends Item> list, Item value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
               if(isSelected && list.getSelectedIndex () != index)
                   return new JLabel(value.getNumber());

               return new JLabel(value.getNumber() +" "+value.getName());
           }
       });
   ```

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks that's almost what i want, but the thing is when the mouse hovers over the dropdown list, its items also change. I want the renderer to change only the items in the textfield component, not in the dropdown.

Comment: See the update. Changed the condition to `isSelected && list.getSelectedIndex () != index`. I think this is the nearest thing to your needs. After all you can set some forground and background colors due to the `cellHasFocus` argument to have a better representation.

Comment: Ok i didn't see the update. Thanks, it's working now.